# java update hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I have a problem with changing values in an HashMap>. First I do this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> countries = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Integer> medals = new ArrayList<>();
medals.add(0); medals.add(0); medals.add(0);
for(int i = 0; i < COUNTRY.length; i++){
    countries.put(COUNTRY[i], medals);
}
```

I fill the HashMap with keys from a static array and add a default value of an ArrayList that is filled with 0, 0, 0. Then I do this:

```
Integer plus = new Integer(1);
for(int j = 0; j < athletes.size(); j++){
    if(j == 3)
        break;
    Athlete a = athletes.get(j);
    ArrayList<Integer> medals = countries.get(a.getCountry());
    Integer medal = medals.get(j) + plus;
    medals.set(j, medal);
    countries.put(a.getCountry(), medals);
}
```

I have an ArrayList filled with athletes that is already sorted by the athlete's results. What I'm trying to do is take the top 3 placed athletes, and update my HashMap value so the ArrayList will have 3 numbers that represent how many gold, silver and bronze medals every country has won.
The problem is that when I try to replace the old value with a new ArrayList it replaces all the values in the HashMap with new ArrayList's instead of just the one with the matching key.

I have no idea what the problem is, any suggestions??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in this piece of code:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> countries = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Integer> medals = new ArrayList<>();
medals.add(0); medals.add(0); medals.add(0);
for(int i = 0; i < COUNTRY.length; i++){
    countries.put(COUNTRY[i], medals);
}
```

You only create a single instance of your List, and associate it with every country.

A possible fix would be to initialize a new List in each loop iteration.

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> countries = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < COUNTRY.length; i++){
    List<Integer> medals = Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0);
    countries.put(COUNTRY[i], medals);
}
```

If your List has the fixed size of 3, why don't you use a simple `int[]` instead?

This is how the code would look using an `int[]`

```
Map<String, int[]> countries = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < COUNTRY.length; i++){
    countries.put(COUNTRY[i], new int[3]);
}
//
for(int j = 0; j < athletes.size(); j++){
    if(j == 3)
        break;
    Athlete a = athletes.get(j);
    int[] medals = countries.get(a.getCountry());
    medals[j]++;
    // last to lines could even be
    // countries.get(a.getCountry())[j]++;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I should've known I made a stupid mistake :P 
and yes I guess int[] is simpler :)

Comment: I struggled with this issue for SO LONG, and this was the simple fix. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use google-guava's [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) . It is design for exactly this situation where you need `Map<K,List<V>>` type of structure. i.e. multiple value for same key.